# Step 1 in proof of denseness of $\Bbb Q$

Tags: analysis, proof-explanation, rational-numbers, dense-subspaces

I am doing the prof for the denseness of $\Bbb Q$.
I want to find $m,n$ in $\Bbb Z$ ($n>0$) such that $a<\frac mn<b$.

My prof says the first step is to find $n$ in $\Bbb N$ such that $bn-an>1$.

And the second step is to prove the following claim: if [left with] two real numbers $r_1,r_2 \in \Bbb R$ [such that] $r_2-r_1>1$, then there’s always an integer between, so there exists an $m$ in $\Bbb Z$ such that $r_1<m<r_2$.

To be honest, I haven’t even got to why the second step is the way it is, however I am confused when it comes to the first step; it’s like the inequality $bn-an>1$ just pops out of nowhere. I’d appreciate some help. Please and thank you.

Comment: It is by the [Archimedean Principle](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Archimedean_Principle). While the page state for the naturals, I'm sure you can extend it to the rationals.

Comment: So, a<b is by the Archimedean principle. We can then go a-b<0.  But again the Archimedean principle says we can attach a positive integer n so that n(a-b)>0. Now, if this is correct then why does our first has us finding n in N such that bn-an>1?

Answer (score 1):

You have$$bn-an>1\iff(b-a)n>1\iff n>\frac1{b-a}.$$And there is such a $n$ by the Archimedian property.

Comment: Ok, but why do we choose 1 instead of 0? Maybe that’s a stupid question but in my previous comment (above) I left work as to my misunderstanding in this way.

Comment: We are assuming from the start that $a<b$. Therefore, $b-a>0$, and so it is trivial that $bn-an>0$.

Comment: does that mean since we already know bn-an>0 that we ignore it? I’m sorry but if this is acceptable I still don’t see why I can’t go in this direction?

Comment: At the same time I feel like it might have something to do with n>N in many of my definitions..

Comment: I am just saying that the inequality $bn-an>0$ is so trivial that there is no reason no mention it. Besides being useless for the proof. On the other hand, the inequality $bn-an>1$ is the first step towards a proof.

Comment: Gotcha when it comes to there being something to actually prove but beyond that, are there any other reasons why we require the difference to be greater than 1 as something that’ll ultimately prove the denseness of Q?

Comment: Yes. Since $bn-an>1$, there is some integer $m$ such that $an<m<bn$, and therefore $a<\frac mn<b$, which is what you want to prove.

Comment: why does the difference being greater than 1 imply there is some integer m such that an<m<bn, and therefore </<?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118949/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-lavorizia-vaughn).